# How to update Bcrypt password with pre("findOneAndUpdate")

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update my hashed password which is stored in the mongodb database. I tried using pre-findOneAndUpdate but is not being triggered. In place of the response I am getting the same hashed password which is in my database.

Below is my code for pre hooks

```
userSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function (next) {
  if (this.password) {
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    this.password = passwordHash;
    this.confirmpw = undefined;
  }
  next();
});

userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified("password")) {
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    this.password = passwordHash;
    this.confirmpw = undefined;
  }
  next();
});
```

Below is my post request code from my route

```
router.post("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const password = req.body.chpassword;

  await userModel
    .findOneAndUpdate({ username: req.params.id }, { password: password })
    .then((userdetails) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        password: userdetails.password,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);

      res.status(404).send(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
userSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function (next) {
  const update = this.getUpdate() // {password: "..."}
  if (update.password) {
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(update.password, 10);
    this.setUpdate({ $set: { 
       password: passwordHash, 
       confirmpw: undefined 
      } 
    });
  }
  next()
});
```

Comment: Its saying password is not defined

Comment: I see, I made a typo. In this line:
`const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);`
just replace `password` with `update.password`
I updated my answer

Comment: I tried searching for get and set update but I did not fully understand the concept. Can you please explain why are we using get & set update instead of using directly this.password ? Thanks

Comment: Inside a middleware of pre "update", "findOneAndUpdate" etc.. "this" returns the Query object. If you search for the Query object in the mongoose documentation, you'll see all the methods that it has, how to access and set stuff on it.